# Library for .NET to tell search engines and humans apart

Tags: .net, iis, http-headers, search-engine, user-agent

I'm looking for a standalone server-side solution to recognize search engine crawlers and other bots from human (interactive) visitors. I expect a `User-Agent:`-analysis-based algorithm. The component would be used to classify requests whether coming from a bot or a human visitor in an ASP.NET (MVC) web site. For humans visiting our international site, an automated redirection to our localized web site based on `Accept-Language:` and/or geolocation is performed. This behavior is unwanted when a search crawler visits our site, which needs to see the site as is without being redirected.

So far I just found lists of bots' `User-Agent:` strings such as [this](http://www.robotstxt.org/db.html) or [this](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php). However, while it's a simple task, instead of making our own component, I'd prefer using a 3rd party one to avoid taking care of updates which would require regular research.

Requirements for a component:

- pure .NET component
- no regular external calls made to outer services to preserve low request processing latency
- update service for the component / its configuration

Alternative: a web service accepting `User-Agent:` strings to be examined. The result would then be cached to speed-up processing of further requests. In this case a further value such as ip-based geolocation service would be a plus.

Commercial options are OK. Limited to recognizing “honest” bots that don't pretend to be something else is OK.

Comment: Something to think about is that User Agent is not a reliable indicator whether a request is from a human or bot. I get bots on my site all the time that use standard browser agents, such as Mozilla.

Comment: @chuex Yes, you are right. I can live with recognizing “honest” bots only. Updated my question accordingly.

Comment: Would like to hear the reason for a downvote.

Comment: Any advice to make this question “more constructive” is appreciated, too. I know this type of questions is sometimes closed as not constructive here at SO, but I can't see a better place where to ask.

Comment: The downvote is not mine, but a possible reason for this is that questions asking to recommend a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used it myself, but one that might work is [UAS Parser](http://user-agent-string.info/download). They have a web api as well as stand-alone installable components (.NET is available).

A quick look at the **web api** indicates that it does have an agent classifier. These are the agent types - from the [User Agent String xml api page](http://user-agent-string.info/api/xmlrpc):

```
typ result
----------
"robot"
"browser"
"mobile browser"
"email client"
"wap browser"
"offline browser"
"ua anonymizer"
"library"
"other"
```

It is unclear what differences exist between the installable (.NET) component and the web api. This will require a little research on your part.

Comment: Looks good, will investigate it. Thanks.